# Is this question on topic?

Tags: discussion

I haven't posted a question here so far, I am wondering if this question would be on-topic for the community.

---

I am part of a team that owns many services. We had an idea to build a list of the services that we own.  That way a user can find the necessary information they are looking for with respect to a service (viz name, package name, source code location, continuous integration site etc).

The idea is to have all the services registered - probably on a database. When the user looks for a service then they should see the service and the registered information. For instance, if the person looks for service `xyz` it should display the package name, project name, project source code repository, and the site information associated with `xyz`.

All of our projects are in java, So I thought of using a derby backend as well as using a html/jsp front end to facilitate the search.  Our db requirements are not too heavy. Seeing that this a very simple requirement where we initially enter all of our services into the database first and the service provides a look-up based on our entries, is there a more efficient way of building the registry in java than one I have provided?

---

I look forward to your answers and thanks for reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is hovering in that Not A Real Question/Too Localized. We can't tell you how to build your site, there are way too many different options available and we have no idea what your resources or skill set is, and even if we did then answers would be so specific that no one else would be likely benefit.

If you have questions about how to organize your code and separate your logic then feel free to ask here. If you have specific questions about getting X to work or why Y is giving you an error then you could try asking on Stack Overflow. Your current question isn't really acceptable though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification